# What are make_shared, make_pair, etc called?

Tags: c++, terminology

There is a formal name for the type of functions designed to utilize template deduction to instantiate their template class counterparts. `std::make_pair` is a prime example of such a method. The term "helper method" comes to mind, but I recall there being a more specific term... I just can't remember it.

Comment: The standard doesn't seem to have any particular name for them.

Comment: I'll vote for "factory method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any more official name than "factory function". I wouldn't call it a "method" because it doesn't live on a class.

There's support for this usage in the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html), as well as in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx) by Microsoft's STL guru, Stephen T Lavavej.